# C++ error: a brace-enclosed initializer is not allowed here before ‘{’ token

Tags: c++, arrays, compilation

Simple question:

I'm trying to initialize an array within a C++ class declaration:

```
using namespace std;
#include <string>
class myClass{
public:
  string myArray[] = {"a","b","c"};
};
```

and I'm getting the error:

error: a brace-enclosed initializer is not allowed here before ‘{’ token

Comment: Are you using c++11?

Comment: You misspelled your comma

Comment: You cannot initialize member arrays other than by value-initialization prior to C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, without a complied C++11 compiler, you cannot initialize a member array in its declaration. You have to initialize array member in your constructor. And don't use open array if you know the number of elements to initialize the array.

Answer (score -1):

The real problem is simply that a non-static array data member may not be declared without a bound. At block scope or namespace scope the initializer will be used to deduce the size, but not at class scope. So just change this to:

```
string myArray[3] = {"a","b","c"};
```

and it should be fine.

Comment: I tried either specifying the size or declaring static and am still getting the same error. I'm not using C++11

Comment: @user1701545 If you are not using C++11 then you are out of luck. It's also concerning that you don't know whether you want this member to be static or not.